# How to allocate memory on multiple GPUs

Tags: python, gpu, cupy

I am using Python and [**cuPy**](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.cuda.ManagedMemory.html) to access GPUs. I have access to **Tesla V100 GPU cluster**, which contains four GPUs (each with 32 GB memory).

**Issue**: I am working on a program that needs to compute simple operations (dot product, multiplication etc) on **large arrays** (in several GBs).  If the allocation is limited to 32 GBs, everything is fine, but beyond that limit, I get an exception (understandable).

**Question**: How can I allocate a **unified memory** that I can use to perform operations on large arrays (beyond 32 GBs)?

**MWE:** The program below can be used to allocate arrays of different size (in terms of memory), specified in GBs.

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np

# Desired memory in GB
desired_memory_gb = 31 # SET this value to greater than 32 GB

# Calculate the number of elements required to achieve desired memory
element_size_bytes = np.dtype(np.float64).itemsize
desired_memory_bytes = desired_memory_gb * (1024**3)  # Convert GB to bytes
num_elements = desired_memory_bytes // element_size_bytes

# Create the array with the calculated number of elements
array = cp.full(num_elements, 1.1, dtype=np.float64)

# GPU
print("Array allocated on GPU...")
```